# XtraLabel DataBinding

Tags: .net, devexpress, xtrareport

I using XtraRepo

```
rt to creating report. I add two labels in designer with names: lblCategoryName and lblCategoryDescription. 

Data binding and show preview:

   public class Category
    {
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string CategoryDesciption { get; set; }
        public Category(string name, string description)
        {
            CategoryName = name;
            CategoryDesciption = description;
        }
    }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Category> catList = new List<Category>();
            catList.Add(new Category("one", "one desc"));
            catList.Add(new Category("two", "two desc"));
            catList.Add(new Category("three", "three desc"));
            XtraReport1 r = new XtraReport1();
            XRBinding binding = new XRBinding("Text", catList, "CategoryName", "Category: {0}");
            r.lblCatName.DataBindings.Add(binding);
            binding = new XRBinding("Text", catList, "CategoryDesciption", "Description: {0}");
            r.lblCatDescription.DataBindings.Add(binding);
            r.ShowPreview();
```

In report I have only first record. How can I write all records.
Thank you!
            }

Answer (score 0):

You should bind data (catList) to Report.DataSource.

```
r.DataSource = catList;
```

see also [How to: Bind a Report to a Collection of Custom Objects](http://help.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument4046)